# How to convert from type Image to type BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing

Does anyone know how to create a BitmapImage from an Image? Here is the code that I'm working with:

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
Image img = Image.FromStream(memStream);
```

Now I have access to this image in memory. The thing is I need to convert this to type BitmapImage in order to use it in my solution.

**NOTE:** I need to convert it to type **BitmapImage** not type **Bitmap**. I haven't been able to figure it out because type BitmapImage takes in a Uri for it's constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8327dd31-2db1-4daa-a81c-aff60b63fee6/)

```
public BitmapImage ImageFromBuffer(Byte[] bytes)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.StreamSource = stream;
    image.EndInit();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: your code works perfect. For some reason though half of the images I run through this come out normal and the other half come out negative. Any ideas?

Comment: @loyalpenguin sorry I have no clue as to why half the images turn out to be negative.

Answer (score 7):

```
Bitmap      img   = (Bitmap) Image.FromStream(memStream);
BitmapImage bmImg = new BitmapImage();

using (MemoryStream memStream2 = new MemoryStream()) 
{
   img.Save(memStream2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
   memStream2.Position = 0;

   bmImg.BeginInit();
   bmImg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
   bmImg.UriSource = null;
   bmImg.StreamSource = memStream2;
   bmImg.EndInit();
}
```

Comment: your code also works perfect. For some reason though half of the images I run through this come out normal and the other half come out negative just like when I ran Bala's code. Any ideas on why this would happen?

Comment: that's cool. I'll see if it's something in my code. Also like 3 out of 25 images aren't displaying yet some of their properities still show like height and width. Is this a memory issue?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily sound like a memory issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need BitmapImage, not BitmapSource?  BitmapImage is a subclass of BitmapSource specifically for making a source in XAML (from a URI).  There are many other BitmapSource choices -- one of the other choices might be better.

For example, WriteableBitmap

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx

You can make one of the size you want, and then copy pixels over to it.

Answer (score 0):

Saving in a memory stream doesn't work for images created in memory. So I improved the already existing answers as follows:

```
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
byte[] buffer = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));

MemoryStream loadStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);

BitmapImage returnValue = new();
returnValue.BeginInit();
returnValue.StreamSource = loadStream;
returnValue.EndInit();
return returnValue;
```