# Create real grayscale images using C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I'm trying to create a real grayscale image, but when my designer checks the file he is saying that the image remains RGB.

You can see the photoshop print here:
[image]

I've tried 2 methods so far:

1) Using the MakeGrayScale3 method:

```
    public static Image MakeGrayscale3(Image original)
    {
        //create a blank bitmap the same size as original
        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);
        newBitmap.SetResolution(original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution);

        //get a graphics object from the new image
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);

        //create the grayscale ColorMatrix
        ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(
           new float[][] 
              {
                 new float[] {.3f, .3f, .3f, 0, 0},
                 new float[] {.59f, .59f, .59f, 0, 0},
                 new float[] {.11f, .11f, .11f, 0, 0},
                 new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                 new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
              });

        //create some image attributes
        ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();

        //set the color matrix attribute
        attributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix);

        //draw the original image on the new image
        //using the grayscale color matrix
        g.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height),
           0, 0, original.Width, original.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);

        //dispose the Graphics object
        g.Dispose();
        return newBitmap;
    }
```

2) Using the ImageMagick.Net library with this code:

```
                            using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(file))
                            {
                                image.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.GRAY;

                                image.Write(originalFile);
                            }
```

If anyone had this problem before or have a clue of what to do to change that..

Thanks!

Original Image:

[image]

Result Image (ImageMagick):

[image]

Result Image (MakeGrayscale3):

[image]

Comment: What file format are you using and how is he checking the image (I can't see your screenshot)? Photoshop has some image profiles and those will always be RGB for jpeg files even if it only contains shades of grey. If it is Photoshop then I think you need to save the file as a .PSD file and set the profile somehow to have it show up as a greyscale image for him.

Comment: can you post the result image? I would like to try to open it with Matlab or other software to make sure it is theimage that is RGB , and not PS that tells you that is RGB.

Comment: He is checking the image on photoshop (I've added the screenshot) and on FastStone Photo Resizer (Photometric option).

Comment: I just tried your Magick.NET example with the latest version and I get an image that only has one channel and is Gray. Are you using the latest version of Magick.NET?

Answer (score 2):

The grayscale format used by jpeg [isn't available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24871466/136285) in the classic `System.Drawing` classes. It is, however, available in `System.Windows.Media`. You need to add `PresentationCore` and `WindowsBase` as references for using them (this will not be portable on Linux).

```
public static void SaveAsGrayscaleJpeg(String loadPath, String savePath)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        BitmapSource img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(new FileInfo(loadPath).FullName));
        FormatConvertedBitmap convertImg = new FormatConvertedBitmap(img, PixelFormats.Gray8, null, 0);
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(convertImg));
        encoder.Save(fs);
    }
}
```

As a bonus, this does the grayscale conversion automatically.

If you're actually starting from `Image`/`Bitmap` class, there are [some solutions around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5783005/395685) for converting between them.

Also you should pay attention to:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all answers but after read the topic that Hans mentioned there they talk about the FreeImageNET library that I'm using to solve my problem.

Using this code I've managed to save the image as a grayscale image:

```
FreeImageAPI.FreeImage.ConvertTo8Bits(newimg)
```

Comment: Looking at the docs of that method, that'll just give you a paletted (indexed) image, not the jpeg 8-bit greyscale format.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is this line:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);
```

If you look at the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7we6s1x3(v=vs.110).aspx) it says:

> This constructor creates a Bitmap with a PixelFormat enumeration value of **Format32bppArgb**.

So, you're just creating another color image. What you need to do is to use [a different constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z132tat(v=vs.110).aspx) to force a different format:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap( original.Width, original.Height,
                               PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed );
```

But then that gives you another issue - you can't paint to bitmaps with that pixel format with a `Graphics` object. There is a `PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale` which appears to work even less.

So, my suggestion would be to to this manually. Use [LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits(v=vs.110).aspx) to get access to the raw bitmap and do the conversion yourself. It is a little bit more work (i.e. you can't use the `ColorMatrix` stuff, and you have to take care to check if the source bitmap is 24 bit or 32 bit), but it will work just fine.

One issue to be aware of is that it's not a "real" grayscale format, it's 8 bit indexed. So you will also have to create a palette. Simply map each of the 256 values to the same, i.e. 0 -> 0, 100 -> 100, 255 -> 255.

Comment: Actually, grayscale jpeg is a format all of its own. It's not just 8 bit indexed.

Comment: @Nyerguds Of course. Unfortunately there's no such format in `System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat`.

Comment: There is in `System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats` ;)